# how to align my logo and my links horizontally inside my header?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid-layout

My logo is not fixed on the left side of my links, it keeps floating, when I change the screen size, and I can not put it right. I want to leave fixed for when I decrease the size of the screen I can correctly see the Hamburger menu working. What is happening is that, for some reason, I can not leave it lined up on the left side. Can anyone help me with this ?

```
<header class="menu-bg navbar">
<div class="menu ">
    <div class = ""> 
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
    </button>
</div>
    <div class="menu-logo">
        <img src="img/MYLOGO.png">
    </div>
    <div class="menu-nav">
            <div class=" collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar" >
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#chaves">LINK_1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#usuarios">LINK_2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#relatorios">LINK_3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#permissoes">LINK_4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a  href="#devolver">LINK_5</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a  href="#deslogar">LINK_6</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/zndj96xw/ ?

Comment: almost, the problem is that the links are outside my header. can you see ?

Comment: I would like this to be on the side of the logo